# sort returned only one line in bash

Tags: bash, sorting, pipe

I have a variable which look something like this:

```
param="David Salad 100\nMark Fruit 440\nNoam Chicken 440"
```

I need to sort it according to numbers and then according to Alphabetic order so the out put should be:

Mark Fruit 440
Noam Chicken 440
David Salad 100

I tried to write the following line:

```
temp=`echo -e $param | sort -srnk3`
echo -e $D
```

But the out put is "Mark Fruit 440 Noam Chicken 440 David Salad 100"
The sort doesn't print any \n 's even though I thought it should.

Comment: `echo -e` is non-portable and its use is discouraged, use `printf` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The sort works

```
$ param="David Salad 100\nMark Fruit 440\nNoam Chicken 440"
$ echo -e $param | sort -srnk3
Mark Fruit 440
Noam Chicken 440
David Salad 100
```

you just have to quote the variable (`"$temp"`) to see the newlines

```
$ temp=`echo -e $param | sort -srnk3`
$ echo "$temp"
Mark Fruit 440
Noam Chicken 440
David Salad 100
```